# Handle Promise from Android WebView with evaluateJavascript

Tags: android, async-await, webview, promise, evaluatejavascript

I'm working with the Android WebView and trying to handle the return of a JavaScript promise from the WebView on the Java side after calling it with evaluateJavascript.

**document.java**

```
Button buttonAnnotations = findViewById(R.id.buttonAnnotations);
buttonAnnotations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        wv.evaluateJavascript("javascript:getAnnotations();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
async function getAnnotations() {
    await pdfViewer.getAnnotations().then(result => {
        return JSON.stringify(result ,null,2);
    });
}
```

If I change the getAnnotations() function to not be *async* and return a string all works fine, so I'm trying to figure out how to handle this promise in the java code to get the result.

I've seen a few similar questions but none of the answers seemed to work in this case.

Comment: The JS Code looks a little bit unusual. If you declare a function async, you should be able to resolve the Promise within the function: `let result = await  pdfViewer.getAnnotations()`. But `getAnnotations` will still return a Promise and not a string, so it won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you are returning a Promise from the async function `getAnnotations` (which cannot be used directly in `onReceiveValue`).

In order to "push" the result from `getAnnotations` back to Android, you have to use the `JavascriptInterface`:

In your Activity you can define:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void onAnnotations(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and register it with:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "bridge");
```

In this case the method `onAnnotations` resists within the Activity which also contains the `webView`. Therefore I use "this" for the first Argument.
The "bridge" is the namespace, where you can find the function onAnnotations on the JavaScript side.

Now all you have to do, is to make the call from JavaScript to Android:

```
function getAnnotations() {
    pdfViewer.getAnnotations().then(result => {
        bridge.onAnnotations(JSON.stringify(result ,null,2));
    });
}
```